# How to check if a 2D list contains a list that partly contains another list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find out if my `Tabu` list (2D) contains a list that partly contains another list.

Like:

```
Tabu = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0]]
Test = [3, 2, 1]
Test2 = [1, 3, 2]
```

Here Tabu contains a list: `[3, 2, 1, 0]` that contains `[3, 2, 1]`, so Tabu contains Test, but doesn't contain Test2 as there are no lists in Tabu that contain `[1, 3, 2]` in this order.

Note: All values of Test must be in a sublist of Tabu to pass.
Changing the lists to sets is not an option. There are no repeating values in Test and only two seperate lists can contain the same value in Tabu.

Edit: More info and clarification

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You say you tried multiple ideas using `all` and `in` - you're on the right path there, please share an attempt you thought would have worked and someone will be able to improve on it or fix it. You should always share some code and explain what happened and what you expected instead, when asking on SO. (by the way, your remark about sets suggests that you don't care about the order of elements, so a sublist of `[6, 5, 0, 4]` would also 'contain' the other list, correct?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the rules. Would `Test = [6, 5, 4]` (the wrong order - so its not a sublist in a list) be a match? If a single number was repeated in Tabu or Test, would you have to match that same number several times?

Comment: I agree with Grismar. Maybe look into the set datatype?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate through the Tabu and check if all element of the Test list are in the sublist of Tabu

```
>>> Tabu = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 0]]
>>> Test = [4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> result = any(all(i in sublist for i in Test) for sublist in Tabu)
>>> result
True
>>>
```